# Executing More Than 2 Dtsx Packages Parallely Using Thread Concept In C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ssis

I have console application which needs to executes totally 17 SSIS Dtsx packages in the below fashion.

[1] At first thread it should execute 3 packages all at once in parallel
[2] At second thread it should execute 5 packages all at once in parallel and so on...

I have heard of a concept called parallelism which is in use for higher versions of .Net Framework 4.0 etc.However I am not sure on how to implement the same in Projcet .

I have a tried a few sample using threads ,here is my code snippet.

```
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Thread First = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FirstThread));
            Thread Second = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SecondThread));
            Thread Third = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThirdThread));
            First.Start();
            Second.Start();
            Third.Start();
    static void FirstThread()
    {
        try
        {
            DTSXProcesser pkgProcess = new DTSXProcesser();
            pkgProcess.ExecutePackage("Customers.csv");
            pkgProcess.ExecutePackage("RouteInfo.csv");
            pkgProcess.ExecutePackage("Items.csv");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Exception in Execution Of Package. Error : " + ex.ToString());
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }         

    }
```

Kindly Help ...

Comment: What do you want to execute in a parallel way? The execution of the Dtsx packages (`pkgProcess.ExecutePackage` inside `FirstThread` for instance) or the method that executes it (`FirstThread`, `SecondThread`, `ThirdThread`) ?

Comment: The execution of the Dtsx packages (pkgProcess.ExecutePackage inside FirstThread as well as the method that executes it (FirstThread, SecondThread, ThirdThread) . I need to achieve both

Answer (score 1):

**With .NET 4:**

Using Tasks:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[]{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(FirstThread),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(SecondThread),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(ThirdThread)
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

or with the [Parallel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989744%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Action[] actions = new Action[] { 
    FirstThread,
    SecondThread,
    ThirdThread
};

Parallel.ForEach(actions, action => action());
```

And for the logic inside your methods (`FirstThread`...) you can implement the same concept (if there is no problem to execute the `ExecutePackage` method several times in parallel for the same instance of `DTSXProcesser`).

If you wonder which one to use you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009181/parallel-foreach-vs-task-factory-startnew) but they are almost equivalent.

**With .NET 4.5 and C# 5** you can use the [`async` `await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) keywords.

Comment: Okay,Thanx .I would need to handle Threads In the Catch/Finally Block something like by checking if thread is alive need a proper managed code to abort it to avoid deadlock conditions. Can any one help me Right Now I am using Thread.ResetAbort(); in Catch I want to manage all my threads to Finally Block Is there A way?

Comment: You mean that you want to **cancel** the execution of other `Threads` if something go wrong in one `Thread` ? I don't see what you mean by *"avoid deadlock conditions"* in your case.

Comment: You can use the `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` when working with `Tasks`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx

Comment: Tasks Is Available With Higher Versions Of FrameWorks ,As you said however Our application should be compatible with lower versions too.I want the thread concept to work for 3.5 framework as well where using System.Threading.Tasks; is not available.

Comment: After the complete execution of process ,I would like to make sure all my threads have completed/ended properly ,if at all incase if any of the thread is not killed/hung ,I would like to check the status of it first if it is alive and if so then I would need to Kill/Abort it.. Thats all for which I dont find a suitable instrunction to put in my finally block.catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Logger.Log("Exception in Execution Of Package. Error : " + ex.ToString());
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
            finally
            {
                
            }

Comment: You will need to keep a trace of your operations (success, error)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581236/c-sharp-threading-run-and-cancel-button-need-to-be-able-to-cancel-long-proccess. Other hint is to use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.90).aspx) (available since .NET 2 and up)